# React - pass selected obj from child state to parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I want to create a simple group creator where users can assign other users into a custom group. So there is the view (app) which contains a form with one text input for the group name and another input field in which I want to pass the data from the child component (selector). The selector lists all users and give the option to select the chosen ones to put them into the component state.
Now my problem is that I don't know how to pass the data from the component state to the view so that they can be used for submitting.

I created a sandbox for this case:
https://codesandbox.io/s/checkbox-state-test-solved-forked-rivhx

And here is the source: 
index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { TextField, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import Selector from "./Selector";

function App() {
  const createAction = () => {
    console.log("fire up post request");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>Create group (parent)</h1>
        <form>
          <TextField
            id="name"
            label="Group name"
            variant="outlined"
            required={true}
          />
          <br />
          <br />
          <p>How to pass the selected values here:</p>
          <TextField
            id="members"
            label="Group members"
            variant="outlined"
            required={true}
            inputProps={{ readOnly: true }}
            fullWidth
          />
        </form>
        <br />
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={createAction}>
          Create group
        </Button>
      </div>
      <br />
      <br />
      <Selector />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

and Selector.js:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Box,
  Typography,
  Checkbox,
  TextField,
  Button
} from "@material-ui/core";

const DATA = [
  { id: "1", name: "First name" },
  { id: "2", name: "Second name" },
  { id: "3", name: "Third name" },
  { id: "5", name: "Fourth name" },
  { id: "6", name: "Fifth name" }
];

export default function Selector(props) {
  const [selectionObj, setSelectionObj] = React.useState({});

  props = selectionObj;

  const onOptionSelect = (option) => (e) => {
    if (selectionObj[option.id]) {
      let duplicateSelectedObj = { ...selectionObj };
      delete duplicateSelectedObj[option.id];
      setSelectionObj(duplicateSelectedObj);
    } else
      setSelectionObj((prev) => ({ ...prev, ...{ [option.id]: option.name } }));
  };

  const isAllChecked = DATA.length === Object.keys(selectionObj).length;

  const onCheckAllClick = () => {
    if (isAllChecked) {
      setSelectionObj({});
    } else {
      let allSelected = {};
      DATA.forEach((data) => {
        allSelected[data.id] = data.name;
      });
      setSelectionObj(allSelected);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Box>
      <Typography variant="h5">Selector (child component)</Typography>
      <Box my={2}>
        {/* Table Header. */}
        <Box display="flex" alignItems="center" borderBottom={1}>
          <Box display="flex" flex={1}>
            <Checkbox
              checked={isAllChecked}
              indeterminate={
                Object.keys(selectionObj).length > 0 && !isAllChecked
              }
              onChange={onCheckAllClick}
            />
          </Box>
          <Box display="flex" flex={10}>
            <Typography variant="h6">Id</Typography>
          </Box>
          <Box display="flex" flex={10}>
            <Typography variant="h6">Name</Typography>
          </Box>
        </Box>
        {/* Table contents */}
        {DATA.map((data) => (
          <Box key={data.id} display="flex" alignItems="center">
            <Box display="flex" flex={1}>
              <Checkbox
                onChange={onOptionSelect(data)}
                checked={Boolean(selectionObj[data.id])}
              />
            </Box>
            <Box display="flex" flex={10}>
              <Typography variant="h6">{data.id}</Typography>
            </Box>
            <Box display="flex" flex={10}>
              <Typography variant="h6">{data.name}</Typography>
            </Box>
          </Box>
        ))}
      </Box>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        onClick={() => console.log("Selected ids: ", Object.keys(selectionObj))}
      >
        Get Payload
      </Button>
      <br />
      <br />
      <TextField
        value={Object.keys(selectionObj)}
        variant="outlined"
        inputProps={{ readOnly: true }}
        fullWidth
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

In the sandbox example you can see that the payload is working, now I need help on how to pass the selected values as probs into the -Group members- field like it works in the input field of the selector component (which would be removed when it works correctly).
Thanks for helping me!

Comment: You should search for Lifting State Up on React's docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `App` declare a function and a new state variable and add value to `TextField`

```
 const [selectedGroups, setSelectedGroups] = useState("");

 const handleSelectedGroups = (selectedGroups) => {
    Object.keys(selectedGroups).length === 0
      ? setSelectedGroups("")
      : setSelectedGroups(JSON.stringify(selectedGroups));
  };


 <TextField
        value={selectedGroups}
        id="members"
        label="Group members"
        variant="outlined"
        required={true}
        inputProps={{ readOnly: true }}
        fullWidth
      />
```

and change `<Selector/>` to

```
<Selector onSelectedGroups={handleSelectedGroups} />
```

in `selector` add `useEffect`

```
 useEffect(() => {
    props.onSelectedGroups(selectionObj);
  }, [selectionObj]);
```

and comment `props = selectionObj;`

Here is the complete code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { TextField, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import Selector from "./Selector";

function App() {
  const [selectedGroups, setSelectedGroups] = useState("");
  const createAction = () => {
    console.log("fire up post request");
  };
  const handleSelectedGroups = (selectedGroups) => {
    Object.keys(selectedGroups).length === 0
      ? setSelectedGroups("")
      : setSelectedGroups(JSON.stringify(selectedGroups));
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>Create group (parent)</h1>
        <form>
          <TextField
            id="name"
            label="Group name"
            variant="outlined"
            required={true}
          />
          <br />
          <br />
          <p>How to pass the selected values here:</p>
          <TextField
            value={selectedGroups}
            id="members"
            label="Group members"
            variant="outlined"
            required={true}
            inputProps={{ readOnly: true }}
            fullWidth
          />
        </form>
        <br />
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={createAction}>
          Create group
        </Button>
      </div>
      <br />
      <br />
      <Selector onSelectedGroups={handleSelectedGroups} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

and

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import {
  Box,
  Typography,
  Checkbox,
  TextField,
  Button
} from "@material-ui/core";

const DATA = [
  { id: "1", name: "First name" },
  { id: "2", name: "Second name" },
  { id: "3", name: "Third name" },
  { id: "5", name: "Fourth name" },
  { id: "6", name: "Fifth name" }
];

export default function Selector(props) {
  const [selectionObj, setSelectionObj] = React.useState({});

  //props = selectionObj;
  useEffect(() => {
    props.onSelectedGroups(selectionObj);
  }, [selectionObj]);
  const onOptionSelect = (option) => (e) => {
    if (selectionObj[option.id]) {
      let duplicateSelectedObj = { ...selectionObj };
      delete duplicateSelectedObj[option.id];
      setSelectionObj(duplicateSelectedObj);
    } else
      setSelectionObj((prev) => ({ ...prev, ...{ [option.id]: option.name } }));
  };

  const isAllChecked = DATA.length === Object.keys(selectionObj).length;

  const onCheckAllClick = () => {
    if (isAllChecked) {
      setSelectionObj({});
    } else {
      let allSelected = {};
      DATA.forEach((data) => {
        allSelected[data.id] = data.name;
      });
      setSelectionObj(allSelected);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Box>
      <Typography variant="h5">Selector (child component)</Typography>
      <Box my={2}>
        {/* Table Header. */}
        <Box display="flex" alignItems="center" borderBottom={1}>
          <Box display="flex" flex={1}>
            <Checkbox
              checked={isAllChecked}
              indeterminate={
                Object.keys(selectionObj).length > 0 && !isAllChecked
              }
              onChange={onCheckAllClick}
            />
          </Box>
          <Box display="flex" flex={10}>
            <Typography variant="h6">Id</Typography>
          </Box>
          <Box display="flex" flex={10}>
            <Typography variant="h6">Name</Typography>
          </Box>
        </Box>
        {/* Table contents */}
        {DATA.map((data) => (
          <Box key={data.id} display="flex" alignItems="center">
            <Box display="flex" flex={1}>
              <Checkbox
                onChange={onOptionSelect(data)}
                checked={Boolean(selectionObj[data.id])}
              />
            </Box>
            <Box display="flex" flex={10}>
              <Typography variant="h6">{data.id}</Typography>
            </Box>
            <Box display="flex" flex={10}>
              <Typography variant="h6">{data.name}</Typography>
            </Box>
          </Box>
        ))}
      </Box>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        onClick={() => console.log("Selected ids: ", Object.keys(selectionObj))}
      >
        Get Payload
      </Button>
      <br />
      <br />
      <TextField
        value={Object.keys(selectionObj)}
        variant="outlined"
        inputProps={{ readOnly: true }}
        fullWidth
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could move the state to the parent and pass down the state and the setState hook to the child. In React you shouldn't be passing state from child to parent.

Answer (score 0):

Just past App data as prop to Selector component:

```
function App() {
  const createAction = () => {
    console.log("fire up post request");
  };

  const data = {name..., someField...}
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>Create group (parent)</h1>
        <form>
          <TextField
            id="name"
            label="Group name"
            variant="outlined"
            required={true}

            HERE YOU SEND THE DATA FROM PARENT TO COMPONENT
            myData={data}
          />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Access to the data prop:

```
    export default function Selector(props) {
        return (
            <h1>{props.myData.id}</h1>
            <h1>{props.myData.SOME_FIELD}</h1>
        )
    }
```

If you want update the data when user insert a input, you can use react hooks to archieve this.